# How to configure beans for springboot tests

Tags: spring-boot, import, spring-boot-test

I have a springboot application with some classes and I try to test it.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(DroneControllerSpringTest.Config.class)
public class DroneControllerSpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private DroneController droneController;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @TestConfiguration
    //@ComponentScan("com")
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public DroneController getDroneController() {
            return new DroneController();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegisterDroneLightweightOverWeight() {
        assertNotNull(droneController);
        assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }
}

package com.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/droneAPI")
public class DroneController {
 //someAPI
}
```

I also tried to make Config class external or scan package "com" to let spring container find the bean DroneController on its own, but no luck. Could you help me, what the problem is?

Comment: this question shows lack of effort, please first read some tutorials/documentation and then if you still have a question ask it about one specific thing that doesn't work

Comment: I followed the tutorials and it didn't help. The code above is like tutorials tell

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to test your method implementations. use @WebMvcTest data annotation to test your controller.

When you test beans use @Test.